# Throw not being catched withing stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following loop in a stored procedure:

```
WHILE (@progress <= @total) BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM test WHERE to_cancel = 1 AND id = @Id)) BEGIN
        UPDATE test SET status = 2 WHERE id = @Id;
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05';           
        BREAK;
    END

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

    BEGIN TRY
        IF (@progress >= 10) BEGIN
            ;THROW 50001, 'Error raised', 1
        END

        SET @progress = @progress + 1;

        UPDATE test
        SET progress = @progress
        WHERE id = @Id;     
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        UPDATE test SET status = -1 WHERE id = @Id;
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05';           
        BREAK;      
    END CATCH
END;
```

The error is being thrown and the loop breaks. However, the `UPDATE` within the `CATCH` is not being executed.

Is there a reason why?

Comment: `WAITFOR` seems highly suspicious in code.  But, how do you know the `update` is not taking place?  Is all this occurring inside a transaction?  My best guess is that `id = @id` doesn't exist in `test`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not using transactions. I know that the `update` is not executing because I'm monitoring the table using `service broker`